# SmoothDivScroll is started from First Element not Continuous

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

I am using `SmoothDiv` Scroll , and adding content when `scrollerRightLimitReached` has been reached.

Here is my code :

```
$("div.recent_articles").smoothDivScroll({
         autoScrollingMode: false,
         hotSpotMouseDownSpeedBooster: 1,
         visibleHotSpots: "always",
         scrollerRightLimitReached: function() {
          console.log("Right Limit Reached");
          getNextRecentArticles();

         }
     });

     function getNextRecentArticles() {
      /* ajax Code */
       success: function(data) {
       /* get HTML STR recent is html str*/

      $(".recent_articles").smoothDivScroll("getHtmlContent", recent, "addLast");

      }

     }
```

After Adding `getHtmlContent` it is moved to first Div, I Want Continuous scrolling  where it ends.

Any Idea, Will be Appreciated

Thanks